# How can I select default version of Netcat in ubuntu

Tags: 15.10, debian, netcat

When I checked `netcat -h` I found out that the **-e** and **Version** option is missing from my netcat. I use Ubuntu 15.10. 
After searching from forums I found out a way to know the version installed and the candidate for it.

```
apt-cache policy netcat
```

I got the following output:

```
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1.10-41
Version table:
1.10-41 0
500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
```

So I installed netcat and I got the candidate version. Now I'm confused about how to select the default netcat version and and **-e** option is nowhere to be seen.

What should be the solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: hi EdiD thanks. It worked. I changed my netcat to netcat-traditional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no installed version because `netcat` is a transitional package. It means it doesn't contain any files.
The package installed (by default) and provides `netcat` is `netcat-openbsd`. You can check it's version:

```
apt-cache policy netcat-openbsd
```

From netcat manual:

<sup>"There is no -c or **-e** option in this netcat, but you still can execute a command after connection being established by redirecting file descriptors. Be cautious here because opening a port and let anyone connected execute arbitrary command on your site is DANGEROUS (...)"</sup>

---

There is also `netcat-traditional` with **-e** option. You can remove `netcat-openbsd` and install traditional version:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional
```

or keep both versions and choose traditional  by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config nc
```

Answer (score 8):

By default in Ubuntu `netcat-openbsd` package is installed. `-e`  option is not available in `netcat-openbsd`. for that you need to install `netcat-traditional` package.

```
$sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional
```

After the installation you have to switch from netcat-openbsd to netcat-traditional. for that type

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config nc
```

you will get some choices like this

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative nc (providing /bin/nc).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        auto mode
* 1            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        manual mode
  2            /bin/nc.traditional   10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then enter selection number of netcat-traditional in the prompt,( here 2 ).

and yes we done it.

to check does it work, type

```
$nc -h
```

you will see `-e` option in the list

Comment: If you need to do this in a script `update-alternatives --set nc /bin/nc.traditional`